# MongoDB Group by String Field inside of an Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I did a lot of research on MongoDB aggregation grouping, but couldn't find a solution.

I have the following document structure:

```
{
  "_id":"6053e0ef22b8e60015a23da8",
  "shoppinglist":[
     {
        "_id":"606ae2e34e4416001538104f",
        "items":[
           {
              "_id":"6071c5ed8f669f0015e6eebe",
              "product_id":"605852c28ea29f0015653d6f",
           },
           ...
        ]
     }
}
```

My goal is to group the items in each shopping list object using the `product_id`, so that my result looks like this:

```
{
  "_id":"6053e0ef22b8e60015a23da8",
  "shoppinglist":[
     {
        "_id":"606ae2e34e4416001538104f",
        "items":[
           {
              "_id":"6071c5ed8f669f0015e6eebe",
              "product_id":"605852c28ea29f0015653d6f",
              "count": 3 //3 items with the product_id = 605852c28ea29f0015653d6f
           },
           ...
        ]
     }
}
```

Can someone help me with this, I'm desperate.

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask

Answer (score 1):

- `$unwind` deconstruct `shoppinglist` array
- `$unwind` deconstruct `shoppinglist.items` array
- `$group` by `_id` and `product_id`, and get required fields using `$first` and get count using `$sum`
- `$group` by `_id` and `shoppinglist._id` and reconstruct array of items
- `$group` by `_id` and reconstruct array of `shoppinglist`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$shoppinglist" },
  { $unwind: "$shoppinglist.items" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        product_id: "$shoppinglist.items.product_id"
      },
      shoppinglist_id: { $first: "$shoppinglist._id" },
      items_id: { $first: "$shoppinglist.items._id" },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id._id",
        shoppinglist_id: "$shoppinglist_id"
      },
      items: {
        $push: {
          items_id: "$items_id",
          product_id: "$_id.product_id",
          count: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      shoppinglist: {
        $push: {
          _id: "$_id.shoppinglist_id",
          items: "$items"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VYFbDTAF_0Z)